# PYTHON (PYQT) - CSV - READING BY ROW

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have `user;password;fullname` in the notepad by row.

My form should only accept user and password when I put it on the line widget but every time I run this, my form exits.

```
def login_button_clicked(self):
    import csv
    with open('user.txt', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in reader:
            us, pa, fn = line.rstrip().split(';')

            if self.username_line.text() == us and self.password_line.text() == pa:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "LOGIN", "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!")
                self.isLogged.emit()
                self.close()
                return
            else:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "LOGIN FAILED", "LOGIN FAILED!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `csv.reader()` it is not necessary to use the `split()` function, since internally it separates it. in the variable row you have the list of elements. So in your case the solution is as follows:

```
def login_button_clicked(self):
    import csv
    with open('user.txt', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in reader:
            us, pa, fn = row
            # us, ps = row[:2]
            if self.username_line.text() == us and self.password_line.text() == pa:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "LOGIN", "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!")
                self.isLogged.emit()
                self.close()
                return
            else:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "LOGIN FAILED", "LOGIN FAILED!")
```